# How to generate random categorical data?

Tags: random-variable

Let's say that I have a categorical variable which can take the values A, B, C and D. How can I generate 10000 random data points and control for the frequency of each? For example:

A = 10%
B = 20%
C = 65%
D = 5%

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Do you want the proportions in the sample to be exactly the proportions stated? or to represent the idea of sampling from a very large population with those proportions (so the sample proportions will be close but not exact)?

If you want the exact proportions then you can follow Brandon's suggestion and use the R `sample` function to randomize the order of a vector that has the exact proportions.

If you want to sample from the population, but not restrict the proportions to be exact then you can still use the `sample` function in R with the `prob` argument like so:

```
> x <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
> prop.table(table(x))
x
     A      B      C      D 
0.0965 0.1972 0.6544 0.0519
```

Answer (score 6):

Using R (http://cran.r-project.org/). All I'm doing here is creating a random list with the proportions you specified.

```
x <- c(rep("A",0.1*10000),rep("B",0.2*10000),rep("C",0.65*10000),rep("D",0.05*10000))
# cheating    
x <- sample(x, 10000) 


prop.table(summary(as.factor(x)))
```

/me Waits patiently for argument over how truly random this is

Comment: You can shorten/simplify your first line to `x <- rep( c("A","B","C","D"), 10000*c(0.1,0.2,0.65,0.05) )` and you don't need to specify the 10000 in the call to sample, that would be the default (though for clarity it does not hurt to specify it).

Answer (score 6):

```
    n <- 10000
    blah <- character(n)
    u <- runif(n)
    blah[u<=0.1] <- "A"
    blah[u>0.1 & u<=0.3] <- "B"
    blah[u>0.3 & u<=0.95] <- "C"
    blah[u>0.95] <- "D"
    table(blah)
    prop.table(summary(as.factor(blah)))
```

I have no doubt this is truly random. I mean, to the extent that `runif()` is random :)

Comment: If the desired frequencies are really probabilities, it would be easier to use the `prob` argument for `sample()`: `sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05))`

Comment: Yeah, that's much cuter. Mine is just a brute force.

Comment: I have actually upvoted this because it shows how the  `sample(,prob=)` works (at least in polish it is called roulette algorithm).

Answer (score 4):

If you're a SAS user, recent versions provide a similar ability to pull from what it calls a "table" distribution - which is what you are looking for, as part of the Rand() function. See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001466748.htm