# How to generate two correlated categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, random-variable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate random categorical data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14158/how-to-generate-random-categorical-data)

For example, let's say I have two variables, `Var1` and `Var2`.

`Var1` can have values A, B and C and `Var2` can have values 1, 2 and 3.

Now the tricky bit:
I want to achieve that conditional probabilities of observing 1, 2 and 3 depend on `Var1`.

For example if `Var1` has the value A, then probabilities are 20%, 30% and 50% for observing 1, 2 and 3. If `Var1` equals B probabilities are 50%, 30% and 20%.

Comment: You have implicitly specified nine categories--all 3 * 3 combinations of the two variables--along with their probabilities.  Why not use the answer to your [previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14158/how-to-generate-random-categorical-data)?

Comment: good idea! will do

Comment: So maybe this should be closed as a duplicate?